# NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".selected"}

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, screen-scraping, scrape

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzrBh.png) This is my first time using selenium, and I would really appreciate if someone can help solve this problem

"NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".selected"}
(Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.114)"

Basically, I found this code on GitHub that says scraping Glassdoor in 10 min which was not the case for me :) took me the entire half day and still unable to figure out the problem and get the df I want. I would really appreciate if someone can help me solve this issue with an explanation.

This is the amended code:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd


def get_jobs(keyword, num_jobs, verbose, path, slp_time):
    '''Gathers jobs as a dataframe, scraped from Glassdoor'''

    #Initializing the webdriver
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    #Uncomment the line below if you'd like to scrape without a new Chrome window every time.
    #options.add_argument('headless')

    #Change the path to where chromedriver is in your home folder.
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=options)
    driver.set_window_size(1120, 1000)

    url = 'https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/Job/london-data-analyst-in-london-england-jobs-SRCH_IL.0,6_IC2671300_KO7,19_KE20,37.htm'

    driver.get(url)
    jobs = []

    while len(jobs) < num_jobs:  #If true, should be still looking for new jobs.

        #Let the page load. Change this number based on your internet speed.
        #Or, wait until the webpage is loaded, instead of hardcoding it.
        time.sleep(slp_time)

        #Test for the "Sign Up" prompt and get rid of it.
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_class_name("selected").click()
        except ElementClickInterceptedException:
            pass

        time.sleep(.1)

        try:
            driver.find_element_by_class_name('[alt="close"]').click() #clicking to the X.
            print(' x out worked')
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print(' x out failed')
            pass


        #Going through each job in this page
        job_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("jl")  #jl for Job Listing. These are the buttons we're going to click.
        for job_button in job_buttons:

            print("Progress: {}".format("" + str(len(jobs)) + "/" + str(num_jobs)))
            if len(jobs) >= num_jobs:
                break

            job_button.click()  #You might
            time.sleep(1)
            collected_successfully = False

            while not collected_successfully:
                try:
                    company_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="employerName"]').text
                    location = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="location"]').text
                    job_title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "title")]').text
                    job_description = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="jobDescriptionContent desc"]').text
                    collected_successfully = True
                except:
                    time.sleep(5)

            try:
                salary_estimate = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="gray salary"]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                salary_estimate = -1 #You need to set a "not found value. It's important."

            try:
                rating = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="rating"]').text
            except NoSuchElementException:
                rating = -1 #You need to set a "not found value. It's important."

            #Printing for debugging
            if verbose:
                print("Job Title: {}".format(job_title))
                print("Salary Estimate: {}".format(salary_estimate))
                print("Job Description: {}".format(job_description[:500]))
                print("Rating: {}".format(rating))
                print("Company Name: {}".format(company_name))
                print("Location: {}".format(location))

            #Going to the Company tab...
            #clicking on this:
            #<div class="tab" data-tab-type="overview"><span>Company</span></div>
            try:
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="tab" and @data-tab-type="overview"]').click()

                try:
                    #<div class="infoEntity">
                    #    <label>Headquarters</label>
                    #    <span class="value">San Francisco, CA</span>
                    #</div>
                    headquarters = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Headquarters"]//following-sibling::*').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    headquarters = -1

                try:
                    size = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Size"]//following-sibling::*').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    size = -1

                try:
                    founded = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Founded"]//following-sibling::*').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    founded = -1

                try:
                    type_of_ownership = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Type"]//following-sibling::*').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    type_of_ownership = -1

                try:
                    industry = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Industry"]//following-sibling::*').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    industry = -1

                try:
                    sector = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Sector"]//following-sibling::*').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    sector = -1

                try:
                    revenue = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Revenue"]//following-sibling::*').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    revenue = -1

                try:
                    competitors = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="infoEntity"]//label[text()="Competitors"]//following-sibling::*').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    competitors = -1

            except NoSuchElementException:  #Rarely, some job postings do not have the "Company" tab.
                headquarters = -1
                size = -1
                founded = -1
                type_of_ownership = -1
                industry = -1
                sector = -1
                revenue = -1
                competitors = -1


            if verbose:
                print("Headquarters: {}".format(headquarters))
                print("Size: {}".format(size))
                print("Founded: {}".format(founded))
                print("Type of Ownership: {}".format(type_of_ownership))
                print("Industry: {}".format(industry))
                print("Sector: {}".format(sector))
                print("Revenue: {}".format(revenue))
                print("Competitors: {}".format(competitors))
                print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@")

            jobs.append({"Job Title" : job_title,
            "Salary Estimate" : salary_estimate,
            "Job Description" : job_description,
            "Rating" : rating,
            "Company Name" : company_name,
            "Location" : location,
            "Headquarters" : headquarters,
            "Size" : size,
            "Founded" : founded,
            "Type of ownership" : type_of_ownership,
            "Industry" : industry,
            "Sector" : sector,
            "Revenue" : revenue,
            "Competitors" : competitors})
            #add job to jobs


        #Clicking on the "next page" button
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//li[@class="next"]//a').click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print("Scraping terminated before reaching target number of jobs. Needed {}, got {}.".format(num_jobs, len(jobs)))
            break
    return pd.DataFrame(jobs)  # This line converts the dictionary object into a pandas DataFrame.
```

Comment: Which line of code gives error?

Comment: Hello thank you for getting back to me, can you please click on the image link just added now to see which line of code gives error. Thanks again

Comment: Did you put Chrome to path?

Comment: Too much info is missing. You should describe what each argument mean in the question

Comment: In other words you are asking to revise the whole program. It will take too much time. For example, currently this program even does not close the browser.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your help! Yes I think I figured out the problem. Glass-door wont grant me access for some reasons so when I changed the url and used indeed it worked thanks anyways

Comment: I even inserted the code into my IDE and tried to run it. But too many things had to be changed. Next time if you ask a question, paste your code, not the one that needs many edits.

Comment: I've submitted edit request for your post. It fixes indentation errors. No action is needed from your side now.

Comment: like what?? can you elaborate?

Comment: It's just to help your post look better

Answer (score 1):

your driver cant find the element "selected". selected is the first job posting that is rendered out to your browser and has classname by default as selected.
try using the xpath instead of class name. type in the following code

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MainCol"]/div[1]/ul/li[1]')
```

To get you element Xpath, go to your browser and select the first job element and copy the xpath.

Moreover, you have used '[alt="close"]' in find_element_by_classname but it should be used in css selector

```
find_element_by_css_selector('[alt="close"]').click()
```